# Hover effect +hyperlink on img

Tags: html, css, flask, hyperlink

I'm trying place pictures as links, while having some hover effect on the image. Neither the hover effect or the link work at the moment.

I tried to use :hover on different elements, I tried to use z-index, I tried to check on selector specificity, but something stops hover effect entirely, but I can't see what's going wrong.

```html
<div class="fourthsection">
 <h1>Recent Projects</h1>

 <div class="projectpic-container">

    <div class="picbox">
        <div class= "imgBox">

          <a href={{url_for('portfolio.index')}}><img src={{url_for("static", filename="neuro-ai.jpeg")}} alt="Project1"></a>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="picbox">
        <div class= "imgBox">
          <a href={{url_for('portfolio.index')}}><img src={{url_for("static", filename="cloudtech.jpg")}} alt="Project2"></a>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="picbox">
        <div class= "imgBox">
          <a href={{url_for('portfolio.index')}}><img src={{url_for("static", filename="statistics.jpg")}} alt="Project3"></a> 

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="picbox">
        <div class= "imgBox">
          <a href={{url_for('portfolio.index')}}><img src={{url_for("static", filename="genetics.jpg")}} alt="Project4"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

```
.fourthsection{
  background-color: rgb(247, 197, 164);
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  z-index: -2;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.fourthsection h1{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  top:2%;
  padding-top:1.5%;

}

.projectpic-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 13%; 
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding-top: 45px; 
  width: 80vw; 
  height: 28 vh; 

}
.projectpic-container .picbox{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px; 
  height: 250px; 
  margin: 8px; 
}

.projectpic-container .picbox .imgBox{
  position: relative; 
}

.projectpic-container .picbox .imgBox img{
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4%;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
    filter: sepia(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.projectpic-container .picbox .imgBox:hover img{
    transform: 0.3s ease-in; 
    -webkit-filter: sepia(0);
    filter: sepia(0);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: 0.3s ease-in; 
}
```

Comment: What's inside `{{url_for('portfolio.index')}}` and `{{url_for("static", filename="neuro-ai.jpeg")}}` ?

Comment: it's a flask web framework , but it's the same as a route to a site would be and a path to a picture, just different format for that framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't know your whole page and I don't know if z-index is needed or not, but if you remove `z-index: -2` from

```
.fourthsection{
  background-color: rgb(247, 197, 164);
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  z-index: -2;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

it works just fine...here's the snippet (I obviously used an image from google with a href directed to google in target _blank)

```css
.fourthsection{
  background-color: rgb(247, 197, 164);
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.fourthsection h1{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  top:2%;
  padding-top:1.5%;

}

.projectpic-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 13%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding-top: 45px;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 28 vh; 

}
.projectpic-container .picbox{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 8px; 
}

.projectpic-container .picbox .imgBox{
  position: relative;
}

.projectpic-container .picbox .imgBox img{
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4%;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
    filter: sepia(100%);
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  
}

.projectpic-container .picbox .imgBox:hover img{
    transform: 0.3s ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: sepia(0);
    filter: sepia(0);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: 0.3s ease-in; 
}
```

```html
<div class="fourthsection">
 <h1>Recent Projects</h1>

 <div class="projectpic-container">

    <div class="picbox">
        <div class= "imgBox">

          <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://besthqwallpapers.com/Uploads/25-8-2016/3005/thumb2-remains-of-bridge-lake-park-kromelow-kromelow-lake-rakott.jpg" alt="Project1"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bravo, thanks, I've been starring at this for 2 days. It was there for a reason, but I go around that in a different way then. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same conclusion as alesssz.
Remove the **z-index: -2;** setting from the **.fourthsection** rule and things work fine. Put that setting back, and the hover action is broken.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html lang="hu" xml:lang="hu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link href="__imghover.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="fourthsection">
            <h1>Recent Projects</h1>

            <div class="projectpic-container">

                <div class="picbox">
                    <div class="imgBox">
                        <a href="portfolio.index"><img src="http://keve.maclab.org/pub/tmp/demopic.jpg" alt="Project1" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="picbox">
                    <div class="imgBox">
                        <a href="portfolio.index"><img src="http://keve.maclab.org/pub/tmp/demopic.jpg" alt="Project2" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>    

                <div class="picbox">
                    <div class= "imgBox">
                        <a href="portfolio.index"><img src="http://keve.maclab.org/pub/tmp/demopic.jpg" alt="Project3" /></a> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="picbox">
                    <div class= "imgBox">
                        <a href="portfolio.index"><img src="http://keve.maclab.org/pub/tmp/demopic.jpg" alt="Project4" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note: I replaced the flask reference with a static img url.

```
.fourthsection {
  background-color: rgb(247, 197, 164);
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  /*z-index: -2;*/
  font-size: 10px;
}

.fourthsection h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  top:2%;
  padding-top:1.5%;
}

.projectpic-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 13%; 
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding-top: 45px; 
  width: 80vw; 
  height: 28vh; 
}

.projectpic-container .picbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px; 
  height: 250px; 
  margin: 8px; 
}

.projectpic-container .picbox .imgBox {
  position: relative; 
}

.projectpic-container .picbox .imgBox img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4%;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
  filter: sepia(100%);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.projectpic-container .picbox .imgBox img:hover {
  transform: 0.3s ease-in; 
  -webkit-filter: sepia(0);
  filter: sepia(0);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: 0.3s ease-in; 
}
```

Comment: Also, you may want to correct "height: 28 vh;" to "height: 28vh;" in .projectpic-container rule. That space beetween the amount and unit may cause trouble later.